# Cannot able to view meta information inside auto completion box in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, ace-editor

As you can see from live [demo](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) kitchen sink example. You can clearly able to view whether the entered word is of type "snippet" or "local".

[image: 3]

But when I integrate autocomplete in the local demo, I do not get that meta information. I had also added the meta tag to my competitors.

[image]

```
    editor.completers.push({
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        callback(null, [
            { value: "foo", score: 100, meta: "local" },
            { value: "foobar", score: 100, meta: "keyword" }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Kindly guide me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Press Ctrl+space

Comment: @Elshan Ctrl + space will open auto completion box, which is working well. What I need is those meta information which you can able to see in 1st image inside red box. I wanted to display those keywords also in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **meta** to your getCompletetions map for them,

```
 functionList = [];

     staticWordCompleter = {
         getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
             callback(null,
                 self.functionList.map(function (word) {
                     return {
                         caption: word,
                         value: word,
                         meta: "Hello world!",
                      };
                 ));
          }
      };
      editor.completers = [staticWordCompleter];
```

So for all the words in your autocomplete, you add their respective meta, which should help you.

Comment: I had edited my question, to bring more insight. I had already added meta tag inside my code. I had also attached the latest screenshot. Kindly go through it please.

Comment: Moreover, I had kept my https://github.com/yashvekaria/ace-terraform-editor-mvp  demo here, you can download it and see editor.html